# Why isn't eq working with my string input in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a file with many rows, all of which look like this:

`name:country:stuff:stuff`

What I'm trying to do is print only the name for that row if the country matches what the user entered. I can not get this to work with the `STDIN`, it only works if I assign a value to the string that matches.
For example, if I put `$country = "USA";` it'll show the name of everyone from the USA, but if I put
`$country =< STDIN>;` and enter country when I'm prompted to it doesn't work.  Here is what I have so far.

```
system ("clear");
print ("Please enter a country\n");

open (players, "playerFile");

while (<players>) {
     chomp();
     @fields = split(':', $_);
     $country = <STDIN>;
     chomp ($country);

     if ($fields[1] eq $country) {

         print "$fields[0]\n";

     }

}
```

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? I've been stuck on this for probably two hours. Thanks.

Here are some lines in the playerFile

```
Roger Federer:Switzerland:6
Stan Warinka:Switzerland:2
Novak Djokovic:Serbia:3 
Ryan Harrison:USA
Andy Murray:Great Britain:4
David Ferrer:Spain:2
J M Del Potro:Argentina:3  
Thomas Berdych:Czech Republic:2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to move your country input outside of your loop.
Like this ....

```
use strict;
use warnings;

system ("clear");
print ("Please enter a country\n");

open (playerfile, "playerFile") || die "No playerfile found";
my $country = <STDIN>;     # Get the country.
chomp($country);

while (<playerfile>) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = split(':', $_);

   if ($fields[1] eq $country) {

       print "$fields[0]\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok I did it exactly like you have it here and nothing comes up still when I type in the country.  I don't know what's going on.

Comment: make sure your player file is called playerFile its case sensitive.

Comment: I did make sure, it works if I just set $country to the one of the countries in the file. Just not during the STDIN.

Comment: Please post some lines from your playerFile

Comment: Sorry I added them in the main question.

Comment: I don't know what I did but it's working. Thank you!

Comment: It's poor style to hardcode filenames into your scripts. Make them arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print ("Please enter a country\n");
my $country = <STDIN>;
chomp($country);

open (my $players, "<", "playerFile") || die "No playerfile found";
while (<$players>) {
    chomp;   
    my @fields = split(':', $_);
    print "fields[0]\n" if ($fields[1] eq $country);
}
```

Comment: I moved it out, but now it still doesn't work.  Nothing happens when I type in a country.

Comment: `chomp` what you read from `<STDIN>` so that there is no trailing newline that messes up the comparison.

Comment: Can you put a bit more effort in fixing *your* program? What you've posted does not work (readline() on unopened filehandle players) out of the box. You just come back with "doesn't work" when someone tries to help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've been working on this for over 2 hours. I have no idea what else to do. Honestly I've done what you guys have told me to do before and it didn't help.